# few functions of graphics.h library are not working in the c file in linux (ubuntu LTS 20.04)

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, bgi

I am working on the linux ubuntu to make a simple application with graphics. Linux and c-language are my project requirements. I have installed the graphics.h library in the linux useing the following commands.

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential

sudo apt-get install libsdl-image1.2 libsdl-image1.2-dev guile-2.0 \
guile-2.0-dev libsdl1.2debian libart-2.0-dev libaudiofile-dev \
libesd0-dev libdirectfb-dev libdirectfb-extra libfreetype6-dev \
libxext-dev x11proto-xext-dev libfreetype6 libaa1 libaa1-dev \
libslang2-dev libasound2 libasound2-dev
```

it tells me that **libesd0-dev** is depreciated in latest version of ubuntu so i install **libesd0-dev** according to the methods suggested on stack overflow posts.
All of the functions of **graphics.h** are working fine on the linux ubuntu except **settextstyle** and **setfillstyle** .
Why it is soo, the functions related to fonts are not working and giving error to implicit function declaration.. Why it is soo.. is there any other library which i can use to deal with font style and sizes in **c** in **linux ubuntu**.

Comment: If this is an implementation of the ancient Borland graphics I seem to remember that font usage required another source file.

Comment: I am new to linux and graphics in c, I can,t understand what you are talking about

Comment: This page about [`settextstyle`](https://home.cs.colorado.edu/~main/bgi/doc/settextstyle.html) says: "The default bit-mapped font is built into the graphics system. Stroked fonts are stored in *.CHR disk files, and only one at a time is kept in memory. Therefore, when you select a stroked font (different from the last selected stroked font), the corresponding *.CHR file must be loaded from disk." But I can't remember (Borland graphics is almost older than I am) more detail, but the link contains example code.

Comment: Okkay i have got the problem with fonts, Thanks.  Now could somebody refer me any solution to this problem

Comment: Welcome! Please post the [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that shows what is "not working" and state the exact compiler errors and/or execution codes. I apologise for guessing the reason.